# Syntax for including images in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

In order to include css in the velocity I'm using the syntax as below in my html file.

```
  #include("css/temp_css.css")
```

What would be the syntax to include the images in html file using velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embedded image You don't need include the file . You can directly have `img` tag in `vm` file itself.

And for above code you can pass some url from the java object.

```
Map velocityObj = new HashMap();
velocityObj.put("imageUrl", "Your full Url ");
```